# How does Windows decide what the "best drivers" are?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-update, device-manager

What criteria does Windows evaluate in deciding what it believes are the "best" drivers for a device?

When pointing Windows 10 to a folder with three driver versions (for an Intel Z390 SATA controller): 17.7, 17.8., 17.9, for some reason Windows deems 17.7 the "best", even if I point it directly to a higher-versioned subfolder.

I know how to override this via "Have Disk", but I'm trying to understand how Windows is making this determination in the first place, what criteria it's going off of. Not just for this device, but future devices, as well.

Comment: Not entirely sure, hench this is a comment not an answer, but I think it scans alphabetically and when it finds a driver that works, it just takes that, and aborts searching for anything else.

Comment: Since driver updates are not handled through Windows Update and not Device Manager, this behavior is handled through Windows Update, and likely comes down to as a simple determination of whatever is the current driver for the device in question.

Comment: I also think "update" looks in the Microsoft Driver Catalogue. Manufacturers put their drivers there and if what is on the computer is the same or newer than the catalogue, it does not get updated. I generally (not always) find this selection (best driver installed) works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows PnP manager ranks driver package properties in order of importance:

Signing

PnP ID match

Driver date

Driver version

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/hh825697(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#understanding-driver-ranking